# A computation problem from Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

The problem states:

Find a $\delta > 0$ so that $|x-2| < \delta$ implies that

(a) $|x^2 + x - 6| < 1$

(b) $|x^2 + x - 6| < \frac{1}{n}$ for a given integer n

(c) $|x^2 + x - 6| < \epsilon$ for a given $\epsilon > 0$

This is what I tried for part (a):

working backwards we have

$|x^2 + x - 6| < 1$

$|x-2||x-3| < 1$

$|x-2| < \frac{1}{|x-3|}$

this is where I got stuck because I'm not sure what to replace 
$|x-3|$ with

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$a)$: $|x^2+x-6| = |x-2||x+3| < \delta|x+3| \leq \delta(|x-2|+|5|) < \delta(1+5) = 6\delta < 1$, if $\delta < \dfrac{1}{6}$. You can take $\delta = \dfrac{1}{6}$.

$b)$: Use part a)'s work you want $6\delta < \dfrac{1}{n} \to \delta < \dfrac{1}{6n}$. You can choose $\delta = \dfrac{1}{7n}$.

$c)$: Use part a)'s work again: You want $6\delta < \epsilon \to \delta < \dfrac{\epsilon}{6}$. Take $\delta = \text{min}(1,\frac{\epsilon}{6})$

Comment: Thank you so much! One question, what is the justification for the step:  δ(|x-2| + |5|) <  δ(1 + 5) ? Why is it that you can replace |x-2| with a 1?

Comment: Its called triangle inequality and I force $|x-2| < 1$ to make calculation easier.

Comment: Another way to think about it is if you do find $\delta>1$, you can always make it smaller and the implication will still be true. So you might as well look for $\delta \leq 1$ and so assume $|x-2|<1$.